Как получить значение ID из поля textField
Подскажите, как получить .id из поля текстового ввода. Что-то не смог нагуглить подобного или не там искал.
HTML
   <div class="textField">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Введите название" id="nameSubdivision">
      <img src="download_file.html?file_id=7">
   </div>

Есть несколько полей текстового ввода, в каждом свой индикатор.
Хотел получить id а затем через перечисление его обработать.
По идее $(this).attr('id') не работает, и .prop('id')

<script>
    $('.textField').on('input', function() {
        const currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(currentId);
    });
</script>


Правильно не работает.... есть Инпут, а событие навешано на div

Очевидно что селектор надо менять.....ну например на input[type=text]  или класс должен быть у инпута

Да так работает, благодарю за помощь.
    $(':input[type=text]').on('input', function() {
        const currentId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(currentId);
    });

